# How to upload strapi js to cpanel

Tags: reactjs, cpanel, strapi

I have developed a react app with strapi as the backend locally. Now I have successfully uploaded the react app on cpanel but I am unable to upload strapi because of the limited resources available on the internet. Kindly assist

I tried using this [article from strapi](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but its too shallow as it does not provide way of doing it

Comment: Your article link is actually just stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Do the build locally.
When you can initiate the build locally you can either upload it to Git or manually zip it(don't include node modules)

Either pull the code from Git or unpack it in the needed directory.
When that's done you can do npm install to validate node modules and serve the application.

I tried the zipping method:

1. Create a new project by `npx create-strapi-app@latest yourprojectname`
2. Add your needed configurations(database credentials to ENV, etc..)
3. Run `npm run strapi build` locally.
4. Package the whole folder into a zip(without the node modules)
5. Drop the zipped file into your FTP or the location where you would like to unzip the package
6. Unzip the package (if you're on a Linux machine you can use `unpack filename.zip` command)
7. If everything is unpacked run `npm install`
8. If all the node modules are installed you should be good to go.
9. Run the application via `npm run strapi start`.